# What does WCF custom class / object get extra "Field" method?

Tags: .net, vb.net, wcf, serialization

When "watching" my object in debug, I notice that the items class (list of t), is duplicated in an itemsField class/Property? Not sure really. In debug I can see this, but using intellisense, its not accessible in code.

Reason for asking... I am sending quite a large amount of data over WCF, and would like to "cut" any unneeded overhead. My items list has 185 custom objects in it, and this seems to be duplicated in the itemsField list that is added to the object.

Is this just an internal .net necessity that gets constructed upon de-serialization for using the classes, or is this extra list being transmitted over wcf together with my actual list? If so, can I choose to drop it? It seems to be an exact duplicate...

[image]

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not wrong, by extra field you mean `extension object`.

This property is used for two basic purpose -

1. In case there is an contract change in the service, additional
   properties are returned back into this object.
2. In case of certain errors while sending data to the WCF service,
   request is returned back into extension object.

**EDIT:**
[image]

Comment: Thanks. But I'm not talking about the extension object. I had thought that might be what you are referring to above. What I have, is an object that has the same name as my list object (I only have one top level list in the object), with the words "Field" appended to it.

Comment: I added an image to the OP.

Comment: @LouisvanTonder Hey ! there is nothing to worry here :-), the additional item named `itemField` what you see in debugger window is simply a `backing field` for `item` property.

Comment: @LouisvanTonder You shall be able to see that a backing filed for each property in debugger window.

Comment: Yeah, but it "bloats" my object. The XML serialization of the object without the (backing field), is close to 4MB. I would hate for it to be used as 8MB in memory.... I guess if I cant do without it, so be it. But am still curious as to "why" it is there...

Comment: Backing field doesn't contain duplicate data, rather property holds reference to the same memory location.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33413/discussion-between-autrevo-and-louis-van-tonder)

Comment: Thanks, I think your last comment sealed it for me :-) I see the backing fields are used for my "one liner" property declarations.

Thanks for the effort with this.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can use tools like [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) or [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) (or a dozen others) to check what gets actually sent.

**Edit:**
I don't know VB, but to me, after looking at the picture, it seems that you have (probably auto-implemented) Properties and you can see your backing fields. They are not two distinct entities with 185 entries, but two variables pointing to the same list.

Comment: I am actually serializing to xml, compressing, and transferring the memorystream over WCF. Inspecting my serialized xml document, the extra "Field" list is not in there, so pretty sure it then does not get transmitted over the wire... Still curious as to what it is, as its weighing down my object with twice the size (in bytes/data).

Comment: I added an image to the OP.